# "Program has triggered a breakpoint" while free memory malloced

Tags: malloc, free

When I free memory, the error "Program has triggered a breakpoint" occur. Check the code below, I wonder where is wrong ?

```
 int SSavep(char *visited, int t, int n, int m)
    { 

        int* map = (int*)malloc(m*n * sizeof(int));
        int* q = (int*)malloc(m*n * sizeof(int));
        int count = 0, cur = 0;
        int begin = 0, end = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                //set value for map
            }
        }
        ..........
        if (t >= map[end]) {
            free(map);
            free(q);
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            free(map);
            free(q);
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: without knowing on what platform you are, and what the parameters m and n are, I could only guess that you have requested too large block of memory and triggered assert in source code of debug library, for example if you are using somewhere in code heap check functions you triggered heap corruption assert. Is memory allocation successful once you continue the execution?

Comment: I checked memory allocation success, and m=n=4, I did not use the location outside the malloced location

Answer (score 0):

the entire code is as below:

static int dir[4][2] = { {0,1},{0,-1},{1,0},{-1,0} };

int SSavep(char *visited, int t, int n, int m)
{

```
int* map = (int*)malloc(m*n * sizeof(int));
int* q = (int*)malloc(m*n * sizeof(int));
int count = 0, cur = 0;
int begin = 0, end = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (visited[i*n + j] == '.')
            map[i*n + j] = 0;
        else if (visited[i*n + j] == '*')
            map[i*n + j] = -1;
        else if (visited[i*n + j] == 'p') {
            map[i*n + j] = -12;
            end = i*n + j;
        }
        else {
            map[i*n + j] = -9;
            begin = i*n + j;
        }   
    }
}

q[count++] = begin;
while (cur < count && q[cur] != end) {
    int i = q[cur] / n;
    int j = q[cur] % n;
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        int ni = i + dir[k][0];
        int nj = j + dir[k][1];
        if (ni < 0 || ni >= m || nj < 0 || nj >= n || map[ni*n + nj]>0 || map[ni*n + nj] == -1)
            continue;
        map[ni*n + nj] = map[i*n + j] + 1;
        q[count++] = ni*n + nj;
    }
    cur++;
}
if (map[end] > 0 && t >= map[end]) {
    free(map);
    free(q);
    return 0;
}
else{
    free(map);
    free(q);
    return -1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error on     >> free(q);

```
for m=n=4

int* q = (int*)malloc(m*n * sizeof(int));
q == [m*n*sizeof(int)] == 4*4*4 == 64 bytes == int[16];
```

Because you wrote beyond the address space reserved for pointer variable 'q'.
check 'count' variable before free(q). I've got 1208, called with:

```
char* visited = new char[100 * 100];
memset(visited, 0, 10000);
int res = SSavep(visited, 0, 4, 4);
```

Btw this algo looks alot like some path finding examining neighboring cells on map and assigning weights, right? If so there are many opensource solutions, why not using them instead of reinventing the wheel? There are links to opensource solutions on wiki Path Finding page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding

check the bottom of the page for links.